# in typescript project: can'it use path alias with Typescript + Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

### Note

> 1. I can use alias in my ts file
> 2. I can't use aliases in my test files 【*.test.ts】

### my configuration

##### 1. Jest.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true, // 开启新的测试用例前，保留之前快照
  preset: 'ts-jest', // ts-jest预设对ts文件测试
  clearMocks: true, // 每次构建测试之前，清除mock调用，实例，上下文信息
  collectCoverage: true, // 依赖收集
  coverageDirectory: 'tests/coverage', // 测试报告生成目录
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts?'], // 测试报告收集范围
  coverageProvider: 'v8', // 测试报告需要的provider供应商: v8 | babel
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    // 模块解析文件类型
    'js',
    'mjs',
    'cjs',
    'jsx',
    'ts',
    'tsx',
    'json',
    'node',
  ],
  rootDir: '.', // 应用所在的根目录
  //   modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src/'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // 模块别名匹配
    '/^@(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1', // 类似 webpack.resolve.alias
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['tests/coverage'], // 测试搜索范围排除目录
  testMatch: ['**/tests/**/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'],
  testEnvironment: 'node', // 测试环境: jsdom 浏览器环境; node
};

export default config;
```

##### 2.tsconfig.json

```
{
  // 编译选项
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    // "outDir": "./dist", // 指定输出目录
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "es5", "es2015.promise"], // 开启ecmascript规则集
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext", // 模块方案, UMD, AMD, CommonJS, System, ESNex, ES2015...
    "sourceMap": true, // 开启sourcemap,需要配合打包工具的devtool-sourcemap功能
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // 允许默认导出
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/"], // 指定包含类型的目录
    "types": ["jest", "node"], // 指定类型的模块
    // Cannot find module '@/common/util' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
    "paths": {
      // 配置模块解析路径
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"], // 类型检查目录
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"] // 排查检查的模块
}
```

when i execute in terminal:

```bash
jest --config ./jest.config.ts --coverage
```

### my test failed：

1. 

[image]

> what hapen, I have configured in jest.config.ts,

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '/^@(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1', // 类似 webpack.resolve.alias
},
```

2. First time out of my typescript typecheck out

[image]

I can't believe it, there was a statement recently, why is it happening now, please help me

Comment: it's worked for well,

```
import { sum } from '../../../src/sum/sum';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});

```

Answer (score 0):

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '/^@(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1', // 类似 webpack.resolve.alias
},
```

according to the statement above

```
import { sum } from '@/sum/sum'
```

it should be written like this：

```
import { sum } from '@sum/sum'
```